# Why do I get IIS 10.0 404 Not found when I call post method from my Web Api

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, https, asp.net-mvc-routing

**Here is my WebApiConfig.cs**

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultRouting",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );

            config.EnableCors();

            // clear the supported mediatypes of the xml formatter
            config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json-patch+json"));


            // results should come out
            // - with indentation for readability
            // - in camelCase

            var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
            json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

            return config;
```

**This is my controller:**

```
//[Authorize]
    [RoutePrefix("api/v1/users")]
    public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
        private DbUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public UsersController()
        {
            _unitOfWork = new DbUnitOfWork();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]User newUser)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**When I call it from Fiddler, I always get 404 Not found for that request. I use Fiddler's composer option and then I execute it.**

[image: Fiddler log]

**I don't really understand what is the issue here. When I try to make a GET request it is working well. In my Web.config I have `<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />`**